# Microsoft Word restart page numbering

Tags: ms-word

In MS Word for Windows 10, if you wish to restart page numbering from "1" in the middle of a large document, doing so is currently a 7 step process.  For example, let's say you have a document with 4 sections and on each section you wanted to restart the page numbering from "1".

I had two related questions:

1. Is there a way that, not involving adding any code to the source material, that a user can restart page numbering with 1 or 2 steps as opposed to 7?
2. If no, did anybody have a script that would allow the functionality described above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set the page numbers to restart by right-clicking on the page number, selecting Format Page Numbers... from the context menu and then, in the dialog now opening, entering the desired start value. Seems easy enough to me actually.

If you want to make it simpler you can add the below macro to your Normal.dotm file. You can then add a button to your *Quick Access Toolbar* that you bind to the macro and the command will be a single click away.

Note that page numbering always works per section, so your document will already have to contain the respective sections.

```
Sub RestartPageNumbers()
    Dim startingNumber As Integer

    startingNumber = InputBox("Start page number at: ", "Restart Page Numbers", 1)

    ActiveWindow.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageFooter

    With Selection.HeaderFooter.PageNumbers
        .RestartNumberingAtSection = True
        .startingNumber = startingNumber
    End With

    ActiveWindow.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekMainDocument
End Sub
```